# Initialization from incompatible pointer type [Android CAF kernel]

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Usually I solve the general compilation errors on my own but with the one I am facing, I m having a hard time to fix. I am porting Android CAF kernel to my device from KitKat branch.
The error (forbidden warning) is
  arch/arm/mach-msm/acpuclock-8960.c:208:2: Initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]

The required file can be found on Qualcomm CAF's git
https://www.codeaurora.org/cgit/quic/la/kernel/msm/tree/arch/arm/mach-msm/acpuclock-8960.c?h=kk_3.5_rb1.9

Can anyone please provid/suggest me with a feasible fix for this? Since the code isn't written by me I am unsure about the fixes I found while searching. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work-around-ed the issue by white-listing the file in gcc wrapper script.